# Using ServiceStack.Text without other dependancies

Tags: c#, xamarin, servicestack, nuget-package

I've tried to make use of ServiceStack.Text package (on PCL & MonoAndroid) without any other dependencies however I cannot get this to work.

From your GitHub page

> FREE high-perf Text Serializers and Core Utils powering servicestack.net
>
> ServiceStack.Text is an **independent, dependency-free** serialization library containing ServiceStack's core high-performance utils and text processing functionality, including: ...

There seems to be a dependency on some License utils as I get an exception in JsConfig constructor at run-time.

I've read elsewhere that some have had to include ServiceStack.Client but this sounds like unnecessary overhead - I'm just looking for (fast) Json de-/serialization without anything else.

Is ServiceStack.Text completely dependency-free? Or does it indeed have a dependency on another package?

**Update:** I should have mentioned earlier it is a Xamarin C# project (developed in VS2015) and I'm using NuGet for package management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET 4.5 or .NET Core versions of **ServiceStack.Text** are dependency-free but all Mobile/PCL platforms require the platform-specific adapters that are in **ServiceStack.Client** which is **minimum** NuGet package you need to use ServiceStack's text serializers or clients in all Xamarin platforms.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @mythz. Are there any plans for this to change any time soon? Would be nice to see these serialization libraries de-coupled for PCL and Mobile (although I appreciate there may be technical challenges to this).

Comment: @killercowuk no changes are planned, it's optimally split into a pure x-plat PCL DLL and platform-specific DLL